# How to get the list of edge values corresponding to all possible paths of a particular length in a graph in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, graph

I have the following graph (corresponding edge values are written in the brackets):

```
L0 -> L1 ('01')
L1 -> L2 ('12')
L1 -> L4 ('14')
L4 -> L5 ('45')
L2 -> L3 ('23')
L3 -> L1 ('31')
```

Now I want the lists of the edge values of all possible paths of a certain length starting from `L0`. So, if `length = 3` (excluding starting node), I should get two lists:

```
['01', '12', '23'] and ['01', '14', '45'].
```

Traversing in a cycle is allowed. I tried using a 2-level dictionary to represent the graph.

```
graph = {'L0': {'L1': '01'}, 'L1': {'L2': '12', 'L4': '14'}, 'L2': {'L3': '23'}, 'L3': {'L1': '31'}, 'L4': {'L5': '45'}}

def find_path(graph, start, depth):
    k = 0
    while k < depth:
        a = graph[start]
        for node in graph[start]:
            start = node
        path.append(a[node])
        k+=1 
    return path 
print find_path(graph, 'L0', 4)
```

Obviously it gives one possible path outputs. But I want all possible ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d make it recursively progress further, until the limit is hit or it cannot progress further.

```
# graph: Graph we are operating on
# node: Node we are starting from
# hops: Number of hops we can still do (edges we can take)
def findPaths(graph, node, hops):
    # if no further hops should be done, we were successful and
    # can end the recursion
    if hops == 0:
        yield []
        return

    # if the node is not in the graph, we cannot go further, so
    # the current path is invalid
    if node not in graph:
        return

    # for every node we can reach from the current
    for n in graph[node]:
        # find all paths we can take from here
        for path in findPaths(graph, n, hops - 1):
            # and concat the edge names
            yield [graph[node][n]] + path
```

Used on your graph (in the given representation) this gives:

```
>>> list(findPaths(graph, 'L0', 3))
[['01', '14', '45'], ['01', '12', '23']]
>>> list(findPaths(graph, 'L0', 4))
[['01', '12', '23', '31']]
>>> list(findPaths(graph, 'L0', 2))
[['01', '14'], ['01', '12']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, poke!! Exactly what I wanted and very efficiently written. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd represent it as a simple `edge:edge` dictionary:

```
links = {
    0: [1],
    1: [2, 4],
    2: [3],
    4: [5],
    3: [1]
}
```

Then you can just iterate over it:

```
def get_all_paths(links, length, start=0):
    paths = [[start]]
    for i in range(length):
        newpaths = []
        for path in paths:
            try:
                for next_node in links[path[-1]]:
                    newpaths.append(path + [next_node])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        paths = newpaths

    return paths

get_all_paths(links, 3)
#>>> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 4, 5]]
```

Conversion of each `[0, 1, 2, 3]` to `[(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)]` can be done in a separate step.

---

It also works with your graph:

```
links = {'L0': {'L1': '01'}, 'L1': {'L2': '12', 'L4': '14'}, 'L2': {'L3': '23'}, 'L3': {'L1': '31'}, 'L4': {'L5': '45'}}

def get_all_paths(links, length, start=0):
    paths = [[start]]
    for i in range(length):
        newpaths = []
        for path in paths:
            try:
                for next_node in links[path[-1]]:
                    newpaths.append(path + [next_node])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        paths = newpaths

    return paths

get_all_paths(links, 3, start='L0')
#>>> [['L0', 'L1', 'L4', 'L5'], ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3']]
```

You can then just convert each path to the `['01', '14', '45']` form.

---

Since you seem to be wondering how to do that last conversion, here's a method:

```
paths = [['L0', 'L1', 'L4', 'L5'], ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3']]

def join_paths(paths, links):
    for path in paths:
        yield [links[a][b] for a, b in zip(path, path[1:])]

list(join_paths(paths, links))
#>>> [['01', '14', '45'], ['01', '12', '23']]
```

`zip(path, path[1:])` will turn `[1, 2, 3, 4]` into `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]`.

The `for a, b in` will take each pair and set `a` and `b` to the items in it.

The `links[a][b]` will then look up the path name from the dictionary.

`yield` returns each item one-at-a-time, so you have to call `list` on the output of `join_paths` to get it into a list.

Comment: Yes that can be done provided I had the option to convert the values separately. My program will just take a graph and length as inputs and give the outputs of the lists of values. So, if you have any way-out how to represent the graph as an input and get the values from the output paths, please tell me.

Comment: I have added my code. Now from what you suggested, I can get the possible path lists. How can I get the lists of values now?

Comment: Updated. I still don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Well, I wanted to know how to convert the path into the values. I'm absolutely new to python. I guess I have to use some sort of list iterator. Never mind, thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, I also did it in another way using two for loops. Yours is more efficient. But, you haven't considered the case when the length is higher, like 6. It should still give the output using the cycle the graph has. But it's encountering the key L5 which has no value and it's throwing error. Can you please fix that?

Comment: Yes, it works now. It's good to think of different ways of doing one thing. Thanks a lot, Veedrac for your time and help.